# Wordpress лишние кавычки

Tags: php, wordpress, cms

При добавление медиафайлов через визуальный редактор, и нажатии кнопки обновить к ссылкам добавляются лишние кавычки. 
В результате это выглядет так `src=""link""` что естественно приводит к ошибке. Более того если еще раз нажать обновить, то вновь дорисуются лишние ковычки `"""link"""` и т.д.

Подскажите пожалуйста с чем может быть связана данная проблема? Плагинов вроде бы никаких не стоит.

`remove_filter();` не помогает.

Comment: Какая версия WP и какой визуальный редактор используете (стандартный или какой-то плагин)?

Comment: 4.3.1 обновитья возможности нет, стандартный

Comment: Ну так может через тему кто лезет, на бекдоры проверяли? Ковырять надо тут wp-includes/media.php, думаю без труда найдете. И вам нужно проверить тему. Она может менять ядро.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50674/wp-editor-adds-html-entities-to-the-content

Ответ заключается где то тут, на сколько это правильное решение это вопрос, но решение.